# Javascript Filtering by multiple columns

Tags: javascript, list, filter

Borrowing code from the post below I am able to filter on 2 columns using the || (Or) operator.
However, I'd like to be able to filter using the && (And) operator.
I have been unsuccessful in my multiple attempts. I could use some help.

[Filtering table multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622127/filtering-table-multiple-columns/43622296)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input0, input1, filter0, filter1, table, tr, td, cell, i, j;
  document.getElementById("myInput0").value = 'Female';
  document.getElementById("myInput1").value = 'Engineering';
  input0 = document.getElementById("myInput0");
  input1 = document.getElementById("myInput1");
  filter0 = input0.value.toUpperCase();
  filter1 = input1.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    // Hide the row initially.
  tr[i].style.display = "none";

  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      cell = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
      if (cell) {
         if (cell.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter0)>-1 || 
    cell.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter1)>-1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          break;
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput0">
    <input type="text" id="myInput1">
    <input type='button' onclick='myFunction()' value='click me' />

    <table id="myTable">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Department</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>Service</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>Service</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Anja</td>
        <td>Ravendale</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thomas</td>
        <td>Dubois</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Deidre</td>
        <td>Masters</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sean</td>
        <td>Franken</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For each cell, you can check each filter separately**, then only change the DOM for rows where all filter conditions are met.

(This example uses a restructured version of your code.)

```js
document.getElementById("myInput0").value = 'Female';
document.getElementById("myInput1").value = 'Engineering';
const
  input0 = document.getElementById("myInput0"),
  input1 = document.getElementById("myInput1"),
  table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

function myFunction() {
  filter0 = input0.value.toUpperCase(),
  filter1 = input1.value.toUpperCase();
  for (let row of rows) {
    row.classList.add("hidden");
    const cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
    let
      filter0met = false,
      filter1met = false;
    for (let cell of cells) {
      if (cell.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter0)) {
        filter0met = true;
      }
      if (cell.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter1)) {
        filter1met = true;
      }
    }
    if (filter0met && filter1met) {
      row.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="myInput0"><input type="text" id="myInput1"><input type='button' onclick='myFunction()' value='click me' />
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Department</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>Service</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>Service</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Anja</td>
        <td>Ravendale</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thomas</td>
        <td>Dubois</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Deidre</td>
        <td>Masters</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sean</td>
        <td>Franken</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Engineering</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. You made very quick work of the problem. I can see that by running the code snippet on this page.  However, I've copied the entire snippet adding the <script></script> tags into Notepad++ and I cannot get it to work.  I am sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The only things I can think of that you may have overlooked are that 1) the `script` element should be the last element inside the `body` (to make sure the HTML has all loaded before the script runs), and 2) the CSS should be in a `style` element inside the `head` (or in a properly linked external style sheet).

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it.

Comment: I have wrestled with this for a few months, getting sidetracked and finding workarounds but I would really like to get this working for my application. I am a SharePoint admin and that is the environment I want to get this working. I have followed your instructions as closely as possible. In SharePoint I add a script editor to the page and add your code.  However, to overcome an error, I use table =  document.getElementsByClassName("ms-listviewtable")[0] instead of the querySelector. It stills works fine in Notepad++.  SharePoint for some reason strips out the Body and Head tags. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no. I have no familiarity with SharePoint. Using `getElementsByClassName` does sound perfectly reasonable, though.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error for I was able to put together some JQuery that will dynamically search the first input, and then search those results for the second input. Note, I am using SP2016. While I've included it here in my post, I could not get the call to "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" to work. I found downloading and storing the file on my SharePoint site worked.  For my requirement I wanted to display my list with grouped rows so I'm using a function to collapse the groups on load.  The caveat is the groups in listview have to be configured as expanded.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<script>
           //If rows are not grouped, remove this function
                $(window).load(function () {
                $(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").click();
                });

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();

         //If rows are not grouped, remove this line
         $(".ms-commentexpand-icon").click();

    $('.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr').addClass('myInputMismatch').filter(function() {
      return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
}).removeClass('myInputMismatch');
  });
  $("#myInput1").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $('.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr').addClass('myInput1Mismatch').filter(function() {
      return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
}).removeClass('myInput1Mismatch');
  });
});
</script>
<style>
 .myInputMismatch, .myInput1Mismatch { display: none; }
</style></head>
<input id="myInput" type="text" Placeholder="Search here 1st..."><input id="myInput1" type="text" Placeholder="Search here 2nd...">
```